# Substrings in C

Tags: c, pointers, substring

Given I have declared:

```
char **string;
```

How do I pass it into another function with a substring starting at a certain position?

I currently have it as:

```
function((*string)[pos])
```

intending it to be a substring that begins at position `pos`.  Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

The type of `string` is `char **`.

`string` is of type `char **`.  (pointer to your string)
`*string` is of type `char *`.  (the string itself)
`**string` is of type `char`.  (a letter in the string)

So you want to offset into the string itself:

```
(*string) + pos
```

which will have type `char *`.

Answer (score 1):

```
char **string;
function((*string) + pos)
```

or

```
char *string;
function(string + pos)
```

Answer (score 0):

`(*string)[pos]` denotes the char at position `pos`. You probably want `(*string) + pos` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the pointer of the whole string to the function along with an integer length, which the function will take into consideration in its logic.

Or, you can extract a specific substring (assuming you want to only trim characters off the front of the string) by using pointer arithmetic:

```
char * x = "Some text";
char * y;
y = x + 5;
```

Now, y is pointing to the string "text". http://codepad.org/icVjE6in

Or, extracting a substring with a specific start and end would require using that and [strncpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strncpy/).

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I know of to do this. Both of them require a `char*` so the string you're working with is `*string` in your case (`string` is the pointer to the `char*` representing the string, so you have to dereference it to get the actual string).

The first is simple pointer addition, as in `(*string) + 7`. This gives you the string starting at the eighth character.

The second is to get the address of the starting character, as in `&((*string)[7])`.

Both of these will only "work" if you're string is at least eighth characters long. In other words, don't try to look beyond the end of the string.